# How to synchronously add html to a carousel

Tags: javascript, css, html, owl-carousel

Trying to build functionality to an ecommerce site where recommended products are added to owl carousel. Currently all 4 products will be lumped into 1 carousel div.

Is there a way to synchronously add each product to it's own div of class owl-item?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d) {
        if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('ltkAsyncListener', d);
        else {
            e = document.documentElement; e.ltkAsyncProperty = 0; e.attachEvent('onpropertychange', function (e) {
                if (e.propertyName == 'ltkAsyncProperty') { d(); }
            });
        }
    })(function () {
        /********** Begin Custom Code **********/
        _ltk.Recommender.Render();
        /********** End Custom Code **********/
    });
</script>
```

See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/czkrfga4/

Comment: You will want to add what code you have tried that is causing the issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Well, prepare the contents you want to be appearing on your slide,
suppose image and price and description
so create your slide as below before you add it on the carousel

```
    var slide = $('div.item');
    var img  = $('img').attr('src','http://...');
    slide.append(img);
    var descr = $('p').text('I am a description here..');
    slide.append(descr);
    var price = '$3.3';
    slide.append($('div').append(price));
    //and then add this slide object to your carousel container with 
    $('owl-carousel').append(slide);
    //Hopeful this will give you some light
```